# Objective C, RestFull Library which supports ARC and Compress Data Automatically

Tags: objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I was using ASIHTTP for my web-service connections, but I decided to move to ARC, and don't want using static library using ARC, and non-ARC part separately. Thus I'm looking for a new Library like ASIHTTP, which let me handle the connection. I just look for a ARC model which compress data automatically before sending them.
Is there anybody have any idea which one is best?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [RestKit](http://restkit.org/).  It's a very solid framework which gives you a networking layer (no need for ASI or AFN) with a slick object mapping layer, and if desired, nice integration with CoreData.

RestKit does support GZIP compression [through the supporting Apple networking classes](https://github.com/restkit/restkit/issues/511) (NSURLConnection provides transparent GZIP deflate support for responses).

As far as ARC goes, RestKit would be a separate dependency in your project, so it really doesn't matter if RestKit itself is built using ARC... if you're using ARC, you'll use RestKit objects the same way as anything else (no need to release, etc.).

Comment: As I told, It is important to me the Library implemented by ARC. Otherwise I used ASIHTTP already and it works.